# Deduce type from literal string

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I want to deduce the parameter types of a function from an string. Similar to what printf does.

Currently I do the following:

```
#include <utility>

// calculate the length of a literal string
constexpr int length(const char* str)
{
  return *str ? 1 + length(str + 1) : 0;
}

struct Ignore {
};

template <char C1, char C2>
struct Type {
  typedef Ignore type;
};

// %d -> int
template <>
struct Type<'%','d'> {
  typedef int type;
};

// %f -> float
template <>
struct Type<'%','f'> {
  typedef float type;
};

// Get type from string
template <const char * const * const STR, int POS, int N = length(STR[POS])>
struct GetType {
  typedef Ignore type;
};

template <const char * const * const STR, int POS>
struct GetType<STR, POS, 2> {
  typedef typename Type<STR[POS][0],STR[POS][1]>::type type;
};

// My dummy class
template <typename... Targs>
struct Foo
{
    void Send(Targs...) const {}
};

// Deduce type for each literal string array
template <const char * const * STRS,  std::size_t N, std::size_t... index>
constexpr auto parseIt(std::index_sequence<index...>) {
  return Foo<typename GetType<STRS, index>::type...>();
}

template <const char * const * STRS, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto makeFoo(const char * const (&a)[N]) {

  return parseIt<STRS, 2>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

The problem is, I have to write Ignore() on my function call...

```
constexpr const char *message[] = {"%d", " hello ", "%f", "good"};
constexpr auto foo = makeFoo<message>(message);

int main()
{   
  foo .Send(10, Ignore(), 20.0f, Ignore());

  return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

What I want is something like (compile-time check only):

```
MyFoo foo("%d Hello World %f %s");
foo.Send(10, 20.f, "Hello");
```

Comment: You have to check at runtime if parameter type corresponds to expected type according string content

Comment: Thank you but I want to have compile time check. (Added to question.)

Comment: You need to parse a static constant string with C++ meta-programming to get template arguments for your MyFoo instance to define the parameters of member Send. But that would require to check byte-by-byte, a lot of variations and limits. Implementing a runtime version would be a better choice.

Comment: @Youka Is it possible to get variable size list of template arguments with meta-programming ?

Comment: @Garf365: with a `std::tuple` (of `char_sequence<Cs...>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 `char_sequence` isn't part of the standard. Would be nice you explain. @Garf365 You simply mean [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). These you can unpack (_head & tail function_) and build an array of type IDs.

Comment: @Youka I know variadic template and I use it (almost basically), but it's difficult to me to imagine how to write something like that `return MyFoo<getTypes<...>::types>` where types is a list of types, pobably constructed recursively

Comment: @Garf365 You can't simply transport multiple types. @Jarod42 's suggestion to use `std::tuple` would be a way to do this with the extra costs to store values. [std::tuple_size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size) returns the size, [std::tuple_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) types. You could write your own tuple-similar class just for types.

Comment: If you are using gcc specifically (and thus compiler-dependant), there are some decorators that you can put on your function declaration that designates it as a printf-like function, and gcc will check the parameters.  But it is limited to only what printf recognizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My newest version: Works with C++11 and GCC 4.8 and Clang. Others not tested.

```
/*!
 * @brief Variadic template contains all parsed types.
 */
template <typename ...T>
struct TypeHolder
{
};

/*!
 * @brief Identifier for non formating sequence.
 */
struct Unknown {};

/*!
 * @brief Identifier for possible formating sequence.
 */
struct Formater {};

/*!
 * @brief Any character.
 */
template <char C, typename TYPE, const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format
{
    using type = typename Format<STR[POS], Unknown, STR, POS + 1, T...>::type;
};

/*!
 * @brief Null-terminator.
 */
template <const char *STR, typename TYPE, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<'\0', TYPE, STR, POS, T...> {

    using type = TypeHolder<T...>;
};

/*!
 * @brief Indicates a formation.
 */
template <const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<'%', Unknown, STR, POS, T...> {

    using type = typename Format<STR[POS], Formater, STR, POS + 1, T...>::type;
};

/*!
 * @brief Formation was a escape sequence for %.
 */
template <const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<'%', Formater, STR, POS, T...> {
    using type = typename Format<STR[POS], Unknown, STR, POS + 1, T...>::type;
};

/*!
 * @brief Formation of an integer.
 */
template <const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<'d', Formater, STR, POS, T...> {
    // Append int to variadic template.
    using type = typename Format<STR[POS], Unknown, STR, POS + 1, T..., int>::type;
};

/*!
 * @brief Formation of an unsigned integer.
 */
template <const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<'u', Formater, STR, POS, T...> {
    // Append unsigned int to variadic template.
    using type = typename Format<STR[POS], Unknown, STR, POS + 1, T..., unsigned int>::type;
};

/*!
 * @brief Formation of a float.
 */
template <const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<'f', Formater, STR, POS, T...> {
    // Append float to variadic template.
    using type = typename Format<STR[POS], Unknown, STR, POS + 1, T..., float>::type;
};

/*!
 * @brief Unknown formatting.
 */
template <char C, const char *STR, int POS, typename...T>
struct Format<C, Formater, STR, POS, T...> {
    // Compile time error for unknown formatting.
    static_assert(sizeof...(T) != sizeof...(T), "Unknown formattion.");
    using type = TypeHolder<>;
};

/*!
 * @brief
 */
template <const char *STR>
struct GetTypeFromString {
  using type = typename Format<STR[0], Unknown, STR, 1>::type;
};

template<typename>
class Foo;

template<typename... Ts>
struct Foo<TypeHolder<Ts...>>
{
    void call(Ts...) const {

    }
};

constexpr const char message[] = " %d %u %% Hello World %d %f";
constexpr auto foo = Foo<GetTypeFromString<message>::type>();

int main() {

    foo.call(int(), int(), int(), float());

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](https://goo.gl/uRMl2s)

Thank you for your help!

Any optimization?

Answer (score 4):

You may do something like that with a `char_sequence`:

```
template <char ... > struct char_sequence {};

template <typename ... Tuples>
using tuple_concat = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Tuples>()...));

template <typename> struct format_helper;

template <typename T>
using format_helper_t = typename format_helper<T>::type;

// end case
template <>
struct format_helper<char_sequence<>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

// general case
template <char C, char...Cs>
struct format_helper<char_sequence<C, Cs...>>
{
    using type = format_helper_t<char_sequence<Cs...>>;
};

template <typename T>
struct dependant_false : std::false_type {};

// unknown format %
template <char...Cs>
struct format_helper<char_sequence<'%', Cs...>>
{
    static_assert(dependant_false<char_sequence<Cs...>>::value, "Unsupported escape");
};

// %% for %
template <char...Cs>
struct format_helper<char_sequence<'%', '%', Cs...>>
{
    using type = format_helper_t<char_sequence<Cs...>>;
};

// %f float
template <char...Cs>
struct format_helper<char_sequence<'%', 'f', Cs...>>
{
    using type = tuple_concat<std::tuple<float>, format_helper_t<char_sequence<Cs...>>>;
};

// %d int
template <char...Cs>
struct format_helper<char_sequence<'%', 'd', Cs...>>
{
    using type = tuple_concat<std::tuple<int>, format_helper_t<char_sequence<Cs...>>>;
};
```

That allow to retrieve the list of type from the literal string.

And then

```
// ...

template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo
{
    // ...
    void Send(Ts... args) const;
};

template <typename T> struct tag{};

template <typename... Ts>
Foo<Ts...> MakeFoo(tag<std::tuple<Ts...>>, const std::string& s)
{
    return Foo<Ts...>(s);
}

template <char ... Cs>
auto MakeFoo(char_sequence<Cs...>)
{
    const char s[] = {Cs..., '\0'};
    return MakeFoo(tag<format_helper_t<char_sequence<Cs...>>>{}, s);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a954835364a67e04)